# Does node-async handle the common 'fetch in parallel' workflow?

Tags: node.js, parallel-processing, node-async

I frequently find myself writing functions to handle an array of items:

- An asynchronous function run many timesin parallel, with each function using a different item of the array as its argument
- A counter that fires once all the functions have completed

Eg:

```
function getThings(callback){
  thingsLeftToCheck = things.length;
  things.forEach(function(thing){
    thing.refresh(function(){
      thingsLeftToCheck--;
      if ( ! thingsLeftToCheck ) {
        callback();
      }
    });
  })
}
```

I frequently use [Caolan's async library](https://github.com/caolan/async) for other workflow style tasks, but I can't seem to find something that corresponds to this workflow. Eg, async.parallel is about running a number of different functions in parallel, whereas what I want is to run the same same function with different arguments:

Does async provide something like this?

Answer (score 0):

Actually it looks like [async.each](https://github.com/caolan/async#each) does exactly this. A quick demo (using timeouts)

```
var items = ['one','two']
var results = []
var doStuff = function(item, callback){
  setTimeout(function(){
    results.push('result'+item)
    callback(null)
  })
}
```

Will return:

```
[ 'resultone', 'resulttwo' ]
```